# What does Source values in Acquisition table mean?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I see the folowing values in Acquisitions table on the Android app dashboard:

1. google-play
2. (direct)
3. google
4. (not set)

Could someone please tells me what's the difference between them? Examples would be the best! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- google-play: the conversion source is from the Google Play Store.
- direct: the conversion source can't be determined by Firebase.
- google: the conversion source is from AdWords campaign. The AdWords account should be linked with Firebase account.
- not set: the conversion source is from AdWords campaign. The AdWords account is not linked with Firebase account.

Answer (score 0):

To add to looptheloop88's reply, we see Facebook campaign conversions in Direct and Not Set. So, it is not just un-linked AdWords, but also Facebook.